# Show that a straight line has a lebesgue measure of zero

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that under Lebesgue Measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ every straight line has a measure of zero.

My try:

Let A = $\{ (x,f(x)), x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ be the set of all points lying on the straight line $y = f(x)$.

Show that $\lambda(A) = 0$.

Let $\{ (a_{i}, b_{i})\}$ be a sequence covering $\mathbb{R}$ with $ b_{i} - a_{i} = 1$ $ \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Define $K_{i} = \{ (x,f(x) - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i}})\times (x,f(x) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{i}}), x \in (a_{i}, b_{i}) \} $

Then K = $ \cup_i K_{i}$ covers A and

$\lambda(K) \leq \sum_{i}(b_{i} - a_{i}) \frac{2\epsilon}{2^{i}} = 2\epsilon \rightarrow 0, \epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Since $K$ covers $A$,

$\lambda(A) \leq \lambda(K)$

Is this ok or I have I missed something or done something wrong?

Comment: Your definition of $K_i$ seems off to me. Do you want $K_i$ to be $K_i=\{ \,(x,y) \mid x\in(a_i, b_i), f(x)-\epsilon/2\le y\le f(x)+\epsilon/2\,\}$? (So, the "diagonal strip" of height $2\epsilon$, parallel to, and centered on, the line.)

Comment: Almost, $f(x) - \epsilon/2^{i} \leq y \leq f(x) + \epsilon/2^{i}$, so you get a rectangle covering a line segment for each $i$

Comment: Each segment $K_{i}$ is a parallelogram with height $b_{i} - a_{i} = 1$ and width $\frac{2\epsilon}{2^{i}}$. I am interested in the measure of the union K of $K_{i}$ since it includes A.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps a nitpick; but I   think it should be stated in your argument why $\lambda(K_i)=(b_i-a_i)\cdot{2\epsilon\over 2^i}$.

Comment: Ok, then I understand. :D Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent work. The only thing left to take care of now are vertical lines.

Comment: Thx for the advice, it is always something you forget. :D

Comment: Is it not possible to skip the whole proof by saying that in $\Bbb{R}^2$ the Lebesgue measure computes the area of rectangles and that the area of a line is $0$?

Comment: @sound wave: Not really. That's a nice heuristic argument, but lines are not rectangles. It's certainly true that Lebesgue measure gives areas, when the set involved *has* an area, but consider $[0,1]\times(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q).$ This is merely a union of non-adjacent line segments, so it "should" have area $0,$ but it has infinite measure.

Comment: You can see a line as a rectangle of zero height and infinite basis, so its area is zero. The set you wrote is "seen" by the Lebesgue measure as a rectangle of height one and infinite basis, so its area is infinite, as you said.

Comment: $0\cdot\infty$ isn't well-defined, so while you could certainly see a rectangle of $0$ height and infinite base, that doesn't allow you to find its "area."

Comment: We don't need to compute zero times infinity, consider the sequence of rectangles with basis $n$ and height $1/n^2$, as $n$ goes to infinity the area tends to $0$.

Comment: @sound wave: By contrast, consider the sequence of rectangles with base $n$ and height $\frac1n.$ The area remains at $1$ for all $n,$ so tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty.$ Does that mean that the area of a line is $1$? Of course not. If you want to treat a line as a rectangle, then to calculate area, you multiply its base by its height. If you can't do that, then you aren't viewing it as a rectangle at all, but as a pathological rectangle-like object. Thus, the rectangle heuristic breaks down.

Comment: Good point. There should be a way tho to extend the concept of an interval with radius $0$ in dimension $1$: in $\Bbb{R}$ the Lebesgue measure computes the length of intervals, so the length of a singleton is $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86577/discussion-between-cameron-buie-and-sound-wave).

Comment: Oops! I forgot to tag @sound wave about the chat.

Answer (score 9):

Great work. Here is an alternative that could make things slightly (just slightly) easier to write down.

First observe that there exists an affine translation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which preserves measure (a rotation + a translation), and takes your straight line to 
$$
L=\{(x,0)\;;\;x\in\mathbb{R}\}.
$$

Now your line has the same measure as $L$.

Now by Fubini
$$
\lambda(L)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}1_Ldxdy=\int_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{y\in\mathbb{R}}1_L(x,y)dy \right)dx=\int_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{y\in\{0\}}1dy \right)dx=0
$$
since $\lambda(\{0\})=0$.

Comment: Doesn't this a priori assume that first integral you wrote is finite?

Comment: Yeah we need finiteness to apply fubini's theorem

Comment: No, if the function is positive you don't need finiteness to commute the integrals

Comment: I think you mean Tonelli, not Fubini.