# Proper way to check if a measurable function belong to $L^p$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Studying I observed that a line is measurable and it's measure is $0$ (you can check it here: [Show that a straight line has a lebesgue measure of zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310260/show-that-a-straight-line-has-a-lebesgue-measure-of-zero)).

Let $\mu(x)$ be a measure. I know that a measurable function can be summable. A function is summable if:
$$\int\limits_Xf(x)d\mu(x)=\int\limits_Xf_+(x)d\mu(x)-\int\limits_Xf_-(x)d\mu(x)$$ and both right side integrals are finite, where $f_+(x)$ is the positive part and $f_-(x)$ is the negative one.

For example taking $f(x)=x$, $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{\bar R}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$, X a set, $\mu$ a measure on $X$:
$$\int\limits_\mathrm{R}xd\mu(x)=\int\limits_0^{+\infty}xd\mu(x)-\int\limits_{-\infty}^0xd\mu(x)=x^2/2|_0^{+\infty}-x^2/2|_{-\infty}^0=+\infty-\infty$$
So I conclude that the function $f(x)=x$ is not summable. Since the definition of $L^p$ is the following:
$$L^p(\mu)=\{f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{\bar R}:f\ \text{measurable}, ||f(x)||_{L^p(\mu)}<+\infty\}$$
Does it mean that the line $f(x)=x$ is not in $L^p$?

Comment: That's correct.  Of course, if you replace $\mathbb{R}$ with any closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$, then $f(x) = x$ is in every $L^p$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Checking if $f$ is summable or not does not correspond to checking if $f$ is in $L^1$? What for the other values of $p$?

Comment: I think the summable property in some way implies the fact that the norm is finite. Obviously if we restrict our domain on subset of $\mathrm{R}$ the norm even more so will be finite.